# Changing from one view to another view onScroll

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working a project. I have a a layout with a `view` at top and a `Scrollview` at the bottom of the `view`. Initially the layout will look like this.

[image]

After I scroll up the bottom layout. The view should smoothly change the the below `view`. And if I scroll down the view should come back to its previous layout.

[image]

As you can see there is a change in the position and size of the `textviews`. How can I achieve this ?

Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/home_parentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@color/AT_charcoal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
        android:background="@drawable/topographybackgroundx">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_header_profile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/top_ExpandedHeader"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/image_invisalignLogo"
                        android:layout_width="108dp"
                        android:layout_height="26dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/invis_logo"
                        android:contentDescription="@null" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/image_profile"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_profile_wht"
                        android:contentDescription="@null" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/number_RelativeLayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/layout_aligner_expanded_change"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/image_alignerNumber"
                            style="@style/BigNumber"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="138dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/textview_alignerTimeChange"
                            android:maxLength="2"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:text="@string/three"
                            android:textSize="124sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textview_alignerChange"
                            style="@style/BodyWhite"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image_alignerNumber"
                            android:letterSpacing="0.03"
                            android:text="@string/days_alignerchange" />


                        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                            android:id="@+id/image_selfie_icon"
                            android:layout_width="96dp"
                            android:layout_height="96dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            app:civ_border_color="#FFFFFFFF"
                            app:civ_border_width="2dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textview_6alignerNumber"
                            style="@style/HeaderWhite"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/image_alignerNumber"
                            android:layout_below="@id/image_alignerNumber"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                            android:letterSpacing="0.03"
                            android:text="@string/aligner_number" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textview_expanalignerNumber"
                            style="@style/HeaderWhite"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@id/image_alignerNumber"
                            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/textview_6alignerNumber"
                            android:text="5" />


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textview_alignerTimeChange"
                            style="@style/LargeHeaderWhite"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
                            android:letterSpacing="0.03"
                            android:text="@string/aligner_change"
                            android:visibility="gone" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button_change"
                            style="@style/TextButtonWhite"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@id/textview_alignerTimeChange"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:background="@color/AT_lushGreen"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                            android:paddingRight="30dp"
                            android:text="@string/changenow"
                            android:visibility="gone" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/dividerline"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/number_RelativeLayout"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:background="@color/AT_line" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/addPhoto_TextView"
                    style="@style/BtnTextBlue18"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/dividerline"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/add_photo" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/goCalendar_TextView"
                    style="@style/BtnTextGold18"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_below="@id/dividerline"
                    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                    android:text="@string/go_calendar" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <include
            layout="@layout/homescreen_scrollview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/layout_header_profile"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Post your `XML` code.

Comment: I think it mostly has to be done through java. In my layout the parent is a `RelativeLayout` consisting of another `RelativeLayout` as the upper view and then there is a `ScrollView` at the bottom of the 1st view. @Heisen-Berg

Comment: Instead of saying, show your code.

Comment: added the layout @Heisen-Berg

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Collapsing Toolbar Layout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html?utm_campaign=io15&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog)

[Example Here](https://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/) and [here](https://www.journaldev.com/13927/android-collapsingtoolbarlayout-example)

Edit: some piece of code

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/expandedImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/beach_scene"

            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
         app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" >


        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sample_string"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: I am not using a `Toolbar`. In my layout the parent is a `RelativeLayout` consisting of another `RelativeLayout` as the upper view and then there is a `ScrollView` at the bottom of the 1st view.

Comment: Added the layout. Check it once

Comment: You will need to change your xml layout in order to get this effect.

Comment: but how should i use your solution without `Toolbar`

Answer (score 1):

Using a Collapse Tool Bar as João said, your code should be like this
and getting my answer as base from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48132158/3117650)

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clipToPadding="false">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="210dp"
        android:background="@color/WHITE">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="72dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <Your Content>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
                android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include
            layout="@layout/homescreen_scrollview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/layout_header_profile"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />
```

On `<Your Content>` is the place where you should put your string. 
Sorry that I can't help more. Your Cody is a little messy and really hard to understand.

Maybe if you edit leaving only the important codes will help.

But maybe [this](https://github.com/flavienlaurent/NotBoringActionBar) library can help you.

Comment: Let me try. I am just confused whether the transition will work or not in this. I need to move one textview from one particular to another particular position. You can see that in the screenshot.

Comment: Yes, that's why I put the library, should help. Without library you may could try put on inside the Toolbar the layout you wanna in the end, make invisible and make visible again when the collapse.